# Condor is not running on all available machines/processors

Tags: condor

condor_status shows 470 total available, 298 unclaimed, but only 172 of my jobs are running at a time. No matter how many times I try to submit the job, I still only get 172. If I change "sockets" I get a few more or a few less, but never close to the 470 available.

My requirements are simple and every machine should meet these criteria:

```
requirements = (((Target.OpSys=="WINDOWS") || (Target.OpSys=="WINNT61")) && (Target.Arch=="X86_64"))
```

I have checked the log files and there seems to be ample disk space and memory for all my runs, and nothing I can see that seems to be limiting the jobs. The only suspicious thing to me is that, for jobs that DO NOT RUN, there is far more disk and memory allocated than used and it seems the cpu is never used.

```
(1) Normal termination (return value -1073741515)
    Usr 0 00:00:01, Sys 0 00:00:00  -  Run Remote Usage
    Usr 0 00:00:00, Sys 0 00:00:00  -  Run Local Usage
    Usr 0 00:00:01, Sys 0 00:00:00  -  Total Remote Usage
    Usr 0 00:00:00, Sys 0 00:00:00  -  Total Local Usage
1047  -  Run Bytes Sent By Job
92422376  -  Run Bytes Received By Job
1047  -  Total Bytes Sent By Job
92422376  -  Total Bytes Received By Job
Partitionable Resources :    Usage  Request Allocated
   Cpus                 :                 1         1
   Disk (KB)            :   428810   400000 117456696
   Memory (MB)          :       19      400      2042
```

For jobs that DO RUN, they typically use < 400 MB of memory and <400,000 KB of disk space. I tried setting these requirements in the submit file, but it did not seem to change anything.

```
368  -  MemoryUsage of job (MB)
376144  -  ResidentSetSize of job (KB)
```

Any clues as to what might be limiting the number of processes I can run?

Answer (score 2):

From condor's perspective, if you see an entry like this in the job log

```
(1) Normal termination (return value -1073741515) 
    Usr 0 00:00:01, Sys 0 00:00:00  -  Run Remote Usage
    Usr 0 00:00:00, Sys 0 00:00:00  -  Run Local Usage
    Usr 0 00:00:01, Sys 0 00:00:00  -  Total Remote Usage
    Usr 0 00:00:00, Sys 0 00:00:00  -  Total Local Usage
```

It means that Condor started the job, and the job exited (that's the "normal termination" message) with some exit code.  In this case, the exit code -1073741515 is, in hex, 0xC0000135.  This is a special Windows exit code which means missing DLL.  Does this application need an DLL which is pre-installed on some of your machines, but not others?

Comment: I do not believe this application needs an DLL that is missing. I can get 170 when with one port and 220 with another (i.e. those additional 50 wouldn't run without the DLL either, right?)

Comment: These "normal terminations" that do not run the programs occur 7 to 10 seconds after it starts "executing on host". Are there condor settings that might cause the job to be terminated if something specific doesn't happen within a specified time? For example, I transfer a zip file and unzip it, which may take a while.

07/12 10:04:07 Job executing on host:
07/12 10:04:14 Image size of job updated: 19260
 0  -  MemoryUsage of job (MB)
 0  -  ResidentSetSize of job (KB)
07/12 10:04:14 Job terminated.
 (1) Normal termination (return value -1073741515)

Comment: Do the jobs that exit with return value -1073741515 always happen on the same machine?  This is pretty clear evidence that the binary is missing a dll, either one that it expects to find pre-installed on the machine, or one that it is bringing along with it.

Comment: Mike Fienen set me straight. The issue IS a missing DLL in a particular version of the software I am using, but the behavior is mysterious... some machines appear to run fine sometimes, but the same machine will fail with 1073741515 other times.

I am using another version of the software and I am getting all the requested cores.

Thank you.